# Python program runs for a week, then fails mysteriously

Tags: python, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, crash

I have a python program that runs normally, then fails after a long time, I don't understand why this would happen.

This is to drive a PiGlow board on my raspberry pi.
[image: PiGlow]

Having nothing better to do with it, I let it display the time in binary format, with clock.py, supplied by the manufacturer to demonstrate the board.

The code looks like this:

```
from pyglow import PyGlow
from datetime import datetime

pyglow = PyGlow()

while True:
    time = datetime.now().time()
    hour,min,sec = str(time).split(":")
    sec,micro = str(sec).split(".")

    # do stuff with the hour, min, sec, write them to the LEDs

# that's all, no delay or anything else, so the loop runs like crazy
```

It will run normally for a day, or a week, and then fail, like this:

```
pi@pi ~/pyglow $ sudo python clock.py    
Traceback (most recent call last):    
  File "clock.py", line 37, in <module>  
    sec,micro = str(sec).split(".")    
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

After some research (on SE mostly), my guess is that when it fails, it's because `str().split(".")` has only returned one value, and the program expects two. Perhaps if it's unlucky enough to land on a second boundary with nothing after the decimal point?

If it matters, it is Python 2.7.

I'm quite new to Python so this doesn't immediately jump out at me.
Can you see what the problem is?
What would you change in this program to prevent this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When microseconds are zero (yes, this is possible once in a while) you don't have a dot in the string representation of seconds.

You can use the Python date/time properties instead of parsing the string representation:

```
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.now().time()
hour, min, sec, micro = time.hour, time.minute, time.second, time.microsecond
```

If you have to have zero padded (02 instead of 2) strings, you can use string formatting:

```
hour, min, sec, micro = '{:02d}'.format(time.hour), '{:02d}'.format(time.minute), '{:02d}'.format(time.second), '{:06d}'.format(time.microsecond)
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides the other answers (Selcuk's answer seems better), you could protect your statement with an exception:

```
try:
    sec, micro = str(sec).split('.')
except ValueError as e:
    sec, micro = sec, '0'
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is happening because you are getting full second without any miliseconds. On better CPU you will get this error after few seconds.

```
>>> while True:
...     time = datetime.now().time()
...     hour,min,sec = str(time).split(":")
...     try:
...         sec,micro = str(sec).split(".")
...     except ValueError:
...         print str(time)
...         raise
...
23:08:23
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: Thanks!  +1 for demonstrating it for me

Answer (score 0):

Stop that happening by doing this

```
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    time = datetime.now().time()
    hour,min,sec = str(time).split(":")
    print sec
    if '.' in sec:
        sec,micro = str(sec).split(".")
    else:
        micro = 0
    print 'sec=%s micro=%s' % (sec, micro)
```

It will happen when you hit an exact second with no microseconds. So if you check for the '.' and if you dont find it set micro to 0.

Some print statements in there aswell to show how it works.

Admittedly it would be better to just treat the time values as numbers all the way through and keep strings out of it.